# mod_rewrite $1 gives me the wrong value

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite

I have the following .htaccess in the /backend folder:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase   /backend
RewriteRule   ^(.*)\.php$   index.php?path=$1   [L]
```

When I visit `http://mysite.com/backend/test/pages/dashboard.php` $_GET['path'] returns the string "index" and not "test/pages/dashboard.php" as expected.

What am I doing wrong? I can't figure this out.

Comment: Are you using any sort of framework, or just plain PHP?

Comment: It's plain PHP on a VPS. Could this be some sort of apache config issue? I can't find anything on this when using google.

Comment: Does `var_dump($_GET)` or `var_dump($_REQUEST)` return anything helpful?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved this by adding the following rule before the other one.

```
RewriteRule     ^index.php$ - [L]
```

TerryE pointed out:

> In a perdir context the rewrite engine loops through the .htaccess
>   files until it gets a clean pass.

mod_rewrite was in other words rewriting the url twice because the result of the first rewrite also matched the rule.

Comment: In a perdir context the rewrite engine loops through the `.htaccess` files until it gets a clean pass.  Your additional rule enables this "last pass" to occur on the second iteration before iterating your previous first rule which would have other wise resulted in `backend/test/pages/dashboard.php` -> `backend/index.php?path=test/pages/dashboard.php` -> `backend/index.php?path=index` ->  `backend/index.php?path=index` (terminates because no change).  Understand my explanation?

Comment: Yeah I eventually figured out that it was doing the rewriting more than once. Adding this new rule with [L] prevents it from rewriting the index.php file. Eventually I changed the extension on the match to .html and fixed it that way too.

Comment: Yup, you could also have just added `RewriteCond $1 !=index` to the existing rule to prevent it firing in these circumstances